# Word for: 'Because of war'

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for, as I feel there probably is, an adjective that means something along the lines of 'as a consequence of war'.

e.g., "The women were bored by the X lack of men." Where X implies that the lack of men is due to some war.

Comment: Oddly, there is not at present an English word meaning "related to war". *Polemic*, from Greek, has developed a very different sense;  *bellic*, from Latin, never achieved much currency and is now obsolete; and *martial* signifies something closer to  *of warriors* than to *of war*.

Comment: @StoneyB: Not so. From M-W - **military** [of or relating to soldiers, arms, or **war**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/military). What we lack is a word meaning ***caused** by war*. It's just that other connotations of *military* don't allow it to be used that way. Unlike, say, *bacterial, viral, etc.*, which we happily use to mean both *caused by* and *related to* bacteria & viruses.

Comment: @StoneyB: Be wary of saying "there is no English word for..." unless you're willing to read through the entire OED first, just to be sure. (Even then, one might still find something in the Urban Dictionary.) Also, as an aside, _bellic_ may be obsolete, but _bellicose_ is not (_bellicose_ was the first word that crossed my mind when I saw this question, but it doesn't fit the O.P.'s purposes).

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Not so. The dictionary may say it means *of war*, but it does so only with respect to the action of soldiers in war.

Comment: @J.R.  I didn't go through the whole OED; but I consulted three thesauruses, and I ran the Greek and Latin roots I could find through the OED, since we ordinarily build such adjectives on Greek or Latin roots. I'm reasonably confident that if there's an adjective out there it's so obscure that it would not serve OP's purposes. In most cases where the word is called for we just use *war* attributively, but that doesn't work here. I go with FumbleFingers' answer.

Comment: @StoneyB: I guess you're right - ["military damage"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22military+damage%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) abounds, but although you could say it means "caused by war", it would be more accurate to say it means "caused by *the action of soldiers in* war". It certainly doesn't fit OP's context.

Comment: @StoneyB 'Bellic' is perfect and, even though it's obsolete, I still may use it! If you post that as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted :)

Comment: I think a single word modifier for this sentence would not be the best way to express the desired sentiment. Do you want a word that indicates that the "lack" of men is due to the fact that they are fighting in a war or killed in action? I don't think I would understand the sentence to mean that women were bored because all their men were killed in war.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must have an ordinary non-compounded adjective, contemporary English seems to offer nothing.

*Warrish* was coined in the 18th century, but was used only in the sense *warlike* and soon died of superfluity; *OED 1* cites *warry* in the 16th century, but the word had nothing to do with *war*.

Today, adjectives are rarely built on native stems; I suppose the cultural sense is that a word which has been around as long as *war* would have already developed an adjective if it was worthy of one. So *-y* is only sporadically productive these days, and *-ish* usually means *sorta kinda like*. One workaround is to use the noun attributively: *war department*, *war materiel*. But *war lack of men* just doesn't cut it.

What's usually done these days is build your adjective on a Greek or Latin stem: *urban* for *town*, *erotic* for *love*, and so forth. Greek-based *polemic* would be appropriate; but, alas, it's long since been confined to wars of words. Latin-based *bellar* and *bellal* are possible but cacophonious (and *bellal* would probably be read as the more familiar *Belial*). *OED 1* offers obsolete *bellical* (Tudor) and *bellic* (17th century). You might revive either of these, though you run the risk of your readers thinking you have both misused and mis-spelled *bellicose*.

Comment: Accepted and +1'd for the useful explanation: Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

There's [**war-caused** shortage](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22to%20the%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22war-caused%20shortage%22&oq=%22war-caused%20shortage%22&gs_l=serp.3...156774.157414.1.157724.4.4.0.0.0.0.63.179.4.4.0...0.0...1c.1.WHSYsOHJkLc&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=b49692da6db40a6a&bpcl=38625945&biw=1116&bih=893) / [lack](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22to%20the%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22war-caused%20lack%22&oq=%22war-caused%20lack%22&gs_l=serp.3...40179.43129.2.43536.12.12.0.0.0.0.82.669.12.12.0...0.0...1c.1.tnj5PyJxdOw&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=b49692da6db40a6a&bpcl=38625945&biw=1116&bih=893) / [disease](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22to%20the%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22war-caused%20disease%22&oq=%22war-caused%20disease%22&gs_l=serp.3...27065.29352.3.29951.10.10.0.0.0.0.95.573.10.10.0...0.0...1c.1.lQ6Sny_APBo&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=b49692da6db40a6a&bpcl=38625945&biw=1116&bih=893) /  [etc.](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22to%20the%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22war-caused%20damage%22&oq=%22war-caused%20damage%22&gs_l=serp.3...5302.8389.6.8845.15.15.0.0.0.0.85.795.15.15.0...0.0...1c.1.JaAzyZ983WE&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=b49692da6db40a6a&bpcl=38625945&biw=1116&bih=893), but personally I think in OP's exact context...

> ["the **war-related** shortage"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22to%20the%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22the%20war-related%20shortage%22&oq=%22the%20war-related%20shortage%22&gs_l=serp.3...10541.14404.20.14835.15.15.0.0.0.1.244.1095.13j1j1.15.0...0.0...1c.1.Mt_yTfxSZJo&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=b49692da6db40a6a&bpcl=38625945&biw=1116&bih=893)

...fits slightly better.

I can't explain my preference, and admittedly there are only ten results in that last Google Books link, but four of them refer to *a shortage of men* in one way or another.

The really specific counts are: [war-related shortage of men](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22to%20the%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&gs_nf=3&tok=hisBZFg4Ktsdh3TWpj88aA&ds=bo&pq=%22war-related%20shortage%20of%22&cp=28&gs_id=tz&xhr=t&q=%22war-related%20shortage%20of%20men%22&pf=p&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&oq=%22war-related%20shortage%20of%20men%22&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=b49692da6db40a6a&bpcl=38625945&biw=1116&bih=893):1, [war-caused shortage of men](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22to%20the%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22war-caused%20shortage%20of%20men%22&oq=%22war-caused%20shortage%20of%20men%22&gs_l=serp.3...266951.268963.16.269250.4.4.0.0.0.0.67.201.4.4.0...0.0...1c.1.NmlaQK8_NoM&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=b49692da6db40a6a&bpcl=38625945&biw=1116&bih=893):6

Answer (score 1):

Not quite a single word, but 'in wartime' fits the bill.

> The women were bored by the lack of men in wartime.

Comment: In fact, you can drop the 'in' and it still works.  "The women were bored by the wartime lack of men."

Comment: But the lack may be felt, and the boredom suffered, *after* the war as well.